# read file with multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: java, file, data-structures, delimiter, csv

I have a file that looks like this:

```
0: 1 2 44 342 5   
1: 6 76 87  
2: 4 90 2345
```

and I want to store every line in a data structure.
For example, set 1 will have these 3 values stored inside it: 6 76 87

I know how to do it with one delimiter but this file has two: ':'(colon) and ' '(space).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First split using the colon delimeter and then split the second part using the space delimeter.

Comment: Yeap. Didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(String line : lines){
  int colonIndex = line.indexOf(':');
  int num = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,colonIndex);
  List<String> nums = parseNums(line.substring(colonIndex+1));
  //do something
}

private List<Integer> parseNums(String s){
  //you say you already know how to do this.
}
```